# Minimum of a function

Tags: calculus

for odd number k,   $3\leq k$, on the plane $x_1+...+x_n=1$, find the minimum of

$f(X)=x_1^k+...+x_n^k$.

What I have done is that by the langrange(?) ,$x_1^{k-1}=...=x_n^{k-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Ths answer makes use of the so-called "Multivariable Extreme Value Theorem", which, for our purposes, basically says that $f$ will attain a minimum over the given domain (you have to check the 'inside' of the domain as well as its boundary).  Here's the procedure you're going to want to undertake (I'm assuming you are familiar with some multi-variable calculus):

1) Find the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) derivative matrix $Df(\vec{x})$ and set this equal to the "${0}$ -matrix" (i.e., the matrix filled with zeroes that is of equal  size with $Df$), meaning set each component equal to $0$. This gives us a system of equations whose solutions give us the critical points $ \vec{c_1},\vec{c_2},...,\vec{c_n}$ of your function (inside the domain).

2) Using your Jacobian, find the [Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) $Hf(\vec{x})$ ("2nd Derivative") and compute $Hf(\vec{c_i})$ for each $i$ (i.e., plug in the crit. pts. into the Hessian). You can use these matrices to determine if your crit. pts. are local minimum, maximum or saddles, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

3) Parameterize the boundary of your domain (i.e., the plane given) as, say, $\phi$. Compute $(f \circ\phi)'$ and set this equal to zero to find the critical points along the boundary (i.e., use the familiar old friend from single-var. calculus, the first derivative test).

4) Plug in all of the points you've collected (from steps 2,3) into $f$ to find the minimum over you're domain, and you are done!

[Note: this procedure is tedious, but is not hard if you are familiar with the concepts being used.]